# PHP - toggle between 2 and 3 divs in foreach loop

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, modulus

I would like to loop foreach in php using twitter bootstrap where the result would be like this.
I have tried in many ways with modulus etc. can anybody help me?

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">Item 1</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Item 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">Item 3</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">Item 4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">Item 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">Item 6</div>
        <div class="col-md-6">Item 7</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-4">Item 8</div>
         <div class="col-md-4">Item 9</div>
         <div class="col-md-4">Item 10</div>
    </div>
```

and so on.
thanks in advance

- I used the translator, sorry!

Comment: this is not a solution asking platform. this is actually problem solving platform. but you can try like this $fl=3; for($i=0; $i<10; $i++){ $fl=(3===$fl?2:3); echo '<div class="row">'; for($j=0; $j<$fl; $j++) echo '<div class="....">Item ##</div>'; }

Answer (score 2):

```
$numRows = 4;
$content = "";

for ($i = 1; $i <= $numRows; $i++) {
    (($i % 2) == 0) ? $k = 2 : $k = 3;

    $content .= "<div class='row'>";

    for ($j = 1; $j <= $k; $j++) {
        $content .= "<div class='col-md" . ($k * 2) . "'>Item " . $j . "</div>";
    }

    $content .= "</div>";
}

echo $content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're outputting this from an array of data, here's one way to do it:

```
foreach (array_chunk($your_data, 5) as $row_set) {
    $first_row = array_splice($row_set, 0, 2); // iterate this and output as col-md-6
    $row_set;  //iterate what's left (if anything) and output as col-md-4
}
```

The exact way you output the HTML is up to you.